# « Tenir compte de » ou « Prendre en compte » ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Est-ce qu'il y a une version à éviter ou est-ce que les deux expressions sont valides ? Sinon, existe-t-il une autre façon de dire la même chose ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le sens est le même. S'il y a une différence, c'est uniquement dans l'usage.

*Tenir compte* se construit intransitivement et ne peut donc pas être utilisée à la voix passive.

> Cette remarque doit être prise en compte.

*Prendre en compte* est une expression plus récente. Jusqu'au milieu du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle, elle a uniquement le sens propre d'intégrer une quantité dans une comptabilité ou une mesure. Je ne sais pas s'il y a une cause particulière à l'entrée du sens figuré dans la langue, mais la montée de l'usage au détriment de *tenir compte* est très nette :

[image: tenir compte,prendre en compte,pris en compte,pris en considération]

On constate également que *prendre en considération*, une expression plus ancienne et moins courante, est aussi devenue légèrement plus rare.

Je pense qu'on a plus tendance à utiliser *prendre en compte* lorsque le domaine est mentionné en complément. Noter c'est seulement une impression personnelle, et que l'usage opposé reste idiomatique.

> *Je tiens compte de ta remarque.*
>   *Je prends en compte ta remarque dans mon rapport.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette explication très précise. Néanmoins, il me semble que pour le dernier exemple, il faudrait écrire "Je prend **en** compte ta remarque", non ?

Comment: @Séverine Merci, c'est corrigé.